# Auto increment employee ID

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I just want to add an employee and after that, the employee ID will also increment. Also that textbox must be disabled

[image]

Also here's my code. All I want is to auto increment my employee ID when I add a new employee. I hope everyone will help me. Thank you in advance. :)

```
<center>
    <form class="contact_form" action="#" method="post">
            <h2>Register New Employee</h2>
            <br/>
            <table>
                <tr>
            <td><label for="emp">Emp ID:</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="emp" placeholder="Emp ID" required /></td>
        </tr>
                <tr>
            <td><label for="name">Name:</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" required />
                    <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" required /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="address">Address:</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="address" placeholder="Full Address" required /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="contact">Contact:</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="contact" placeholder="Contact Number" required /></td>
        </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="type">Type:</label></td>
                    <td><select name="type" id="type">
                        <option>Type of Employee</option>
                        <option>Contractual</option>
                        <option>Regular</option>
                    </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
            <td><label for="salary">Salary:</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="salary" placeholder="Emp Salary" required /></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
            <br/>
            <button class="submit" name="submit" type="submit" onclick="message()">Submit</button>
            <button class="reset" name="reset" type="reset">Clear</button>
        </form>
        <?php
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            include 'alqdb.php';
                $emp=$_POST['emp'];
                $fname= $_POST['fname'];
                $lname=$_POST['lname'];
                $address=$_POST['address'];
                $contact=$_POST['contact'];
                $type=$_POST['type'];
                $salary=$_POST['salary'];
            mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO employee (EmpID,EmpFName,EmpLName,EmpAddress,ContactNumber,TypeofEmployee,Salary)
            VALUES ('$emp','$fname','$lname','$address','$contact','$type','$salary')");
        }
        ?>
    </center>
</body>
<script language="javascript">
    function message() {
        alert("Successfully added!");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Add these query in table EmpID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY

Comment: Part of the problem is, if you set it to autoincrement, you're not going to know what the key is until you actually create the row in the database.  If you just want it to be the table's primary key, the user never needs to see it.  Note that an ID isn't actually a number (even if it is a string of digits), so you often want some sort of leading character.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I really appreciate it, but can you edit my codes? to visualize it? thank you in advance. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have an EmpID like EMP001

this code will work:

```
public function autoincemp()
{
    global $value2;
    $query = "SELECT empid from tbemployee order by empid desc LIMIT 1";
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();

    if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $value2 = $row['empid'];
        $value2 = substr($value2, 3, 5);
        $value2 = (int) $value2 + 1;
        $value2 = "EMP" . sprintf('%04s', $value2);
        $value = $value2;
        return $value;
    } else {
        $value2 = "EMP0001";
        $value = $value2;
        return $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: where can I put it? :)

Answer (score 0):

Place `AUTO_INCREMENT` attribute to `emp_id` column in your DB. Remove that EMP ID field from your UI.

The `AUTO_INCREMENT` attribute can be used to generate a unique identity for new rows. Means, `AUTO_INCREMENT` automatically insert new incremented id for that field on each `INSERT query`

**[Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html)**

Comment: If any of the post is useful, you are suppose to up-vote and select that answer. That will help other members.

Comment: ohh. ok2. haha. :) I'm still new in this, btw thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could modify your database to include [AUTO_INCREMENT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html) in EmpID.

You can disable `input` by doing `<input type="text" name="emp" placeholder="Emp ID" required disabled />`

Answer (score 0):

You can hide Emp ID code and change `input type="text"` to `input type="hidden"` and remove `required` in your form.
Now just use `AUTO_INCREMENT` for `EmpId` in your table.

Answer (score 0):

It's late but you can do this,

```
$id = 1; //Your last record Id + 1
str_pad($id, 3, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Hope this helps someone.

[Reference](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/auto-increment-numbers-in-php/3073/8)

Answer (score -1):

```
REATE TABLE dbo.tblUsers
  (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
   UserID AS 'UID' + RIGHT('00000000' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(8)), 8) PERSISTED,
   .... your other columns here....
  )
```

Now, every time you insert a row into tblUsers without specifying values for ID or UserID:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.tblUsersCol1, Col2, ..., ColN)
VALUES (Val1, Val2, ....., ValN)
```

Comment: The answer should be related to MySQL as the question is mentioning this database.